# Does std::byte constructor extract LSB or MSB from integer?

Tags: c++, c++17, std-byte

I'm struggling to understand the following line of code:

```cpp
if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, bool>)
{
    std::byte change = std::byte(static_cast<uint32_t>(in) << m_addr[1]);
    std::byte mask = ~std::byte(1u << m_addr[1]);
    dataBlock[m_addr[0]] = (dataBlock[m_addr[0]] & mask) | change;
}
```

where `dataBlock` is a `std::vector<std::byte>`, `T` is `in`'s type, and `m_addr` is a `std::array<std::byte, 2>`. This does bit shifting in order to store the value of a bool inside of a byte. My question is regarding the first line inside the `if` statement. For this example, I'll use `in = 1` and `m_addr[1] = 3`.

From my understanding, `static_cast<uint32_t>(in)` creates a `uint32_t` given by `00000000,00000000,00000000,00000001`; the left-shift operator turns this into `00000000,00000000,00000000,00001000`, and then this is transformed to an `std::byte`.

How does `std::byte` choose the byte to store? I assume it stores the LSB, so `00001000`, but I couldn't find any reference confirming this. Is it possible for it to store the MSB (so `00000000`)? If it is, how can I make the below implementation platform-independent?

Comment: Except for bitwise operations, all conversions and expressions in C++ are defined in terms of _values_ of the objects. Their representation in memory doesn't matter. With C++20 even the bitwise operations are fully defined in terms of their values. How a result value is then represented in memory, e.g. with little-endian or big-endian byte representation, is dependent on the representation chosen for the result type by the implementation, but has no relevance for any values.

Comment: So, in order to store the MSB all you need is to shift right by `32-CHAR_BIT`, i.e. typically `32-8`, i.e. `24` before casting to `std::byte` and that has no dependence on implementation or platform whatsoever.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The definition of `std::byte` is: `enum class byte : unsigned char {};` (per `[cstddef.syn]`)

Thus, when creating a `std::byte` from a `uint32_t`, the following applies `[expr.static.cast]/10`

> A value of integral or enumeration type can be explicitly converted to a complete enumeration type. If the enumeration type has a fixed underlying type, the value is first converted to that type by integral conversion, if necessary, and then to the enumeration type

From which `[conv.integral]/2` applies:

> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [ Note: In a two’s complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is
> no truncation). —end note ]

Thus, in your example, you will get the least significant byte.

Note: references from N4713 (C++17 draft)